# Probability that a randomly picked object is broken and it was made by machine #3

Tags: probability, statistics

Three machines S1, S2, S3 are producing products with a ratio of 60:30:10. Machine S1 makes 2%, S2 makes 3% and S3 makes 4% of broken items. What is the probability that a randomly picked items is broken and it was made by machine S3?

My idea is to find the probability that a object picket at random was made by machine S3 and then find the probability that that item is broken and multiply those probabilites. Is this correct?

It would be 0.1*0.04 = 0.004

Second question: what is the probability that if a randomly picked object that is broken is made by machine S3. This one sounds the same as the first. I think this one is solved by finding the number of broken items made by machine S3 and dividing it by total number of broken items.

So like this 25/4 = 0.16

Comment: Yes, that seems right.

Comment: Well, except that the ratio is upside down. $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1):

Correct.

Let $B$ be the event of an item being broken, and $S_1,S_2,S_3$ the events of the items coming from those machines.

So, yes, $\mathsf P(B\cap S_3)$ $= \mathsf P(B\mid S_3)\mathsf P(S_3)\\=(0.04)\cdot(0.10)\\=0.004$

Then you seek $\mathsf P(S_3\mid B)$ $= \mathsf P(B\mid S_3)\mathsf P(S_3)\div\left(\sum_{k=1}^3\mathsf P(B\mid S_k)\mathsf P(S_k)\right)\\=(4\cdot 1)\div(2\cdot 6+3\cdot 3+4\cdot 1)\\=4/25$